# How to keep the content of a ui-view between different states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My application has 3 'ui-views':

- nav@
- main@
- side@

my states whitin the router are like this:

```
.state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
        'nav@':  { templateUrl: "views/navigation/main.html" },
        'main@': { templateUrl: "views/home/main.html" },
        'side@': { templateUrl: "views/home/side.html" }
    }
})
```

this one works fine, all three views are rendered.

```
.state('home.detail', {
    url: "/{id}",
    views: {
        'side@': { templateUrl: "views/home/side.html" }
    }
})
```

This one works also, only the 'side@' view is updated.

Now for the third route, I want to keep the "nav@" view in the same state, like it is done in the "home.detail" route for the 'main@' and 'nav@' views.

```
.state('seminar', {
    url: "/seminar/{id}",
    views: {
        'main@': { templateUrl: "views/seminars/main.html" },
        'side@': { templateUrl: "views/seminars/side.html" }
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, the 'nav@' view is rendered blank when opening the route. Is there a way to tell angular to not clear the view and keep the content?

I could declare the 'nav@' template, but I was wondering if there is a way around this.